# Regular expression in case statement

Tags: bash, shell, case-statement

I am trying to filter out some strings using case statement.

```
case $HOST in     
          Linux|Windows|Storage*)
```

I want to filter out the hosts which have names like this

1. test_prd_linux
2. test_prd_windows

How can i include `*prd*` in the above `case` statment? Something like this?

```
case $HOST in  
       Linux|Windows|Storage|*prd*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are globs, not regular expressions.

Yes, the glob `*prd*` will match the cases you have as examples (though I would use the more specific pattern `*_prd_*` if these examples are representative).

However, you also changed `Storage*` to `Storage`, so this will no longer match some strings it used to match. Perhaps put the glob star back.

```
case $HOST in
    Linux|Windows|Storage*|*_prd_*)
```